# How to loop over a string's characterss?

Tags: php, string

Basically, I have an array of strings, and I want to check if each character in each string is in a predefined `$source` string. Here is how I think it should be done:

```
$source = "abcdef";
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach(char in $value) {
        if(char is not in source)
            unset($array[$key]); //remove the value from array
    }
}
```

If this is a correct logic, how to implement the `foreach` and the `if` parts?

Comment: Try exploding your $source to an array of characters, and then use [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) in your loop

Comment: So, basically I should call `$source_array = explode("", $source);` and do the same for the `$value`? Empty `delimiter` returns False. What should it be?

Comment: Use [str_split()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$array = array('1' => 'cab', '2' => 'bad', '3' => 'zoo');
$source = "abcdef";
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $split = str_split($value);
    foreach($split as $char){
        $pos = strrpos($source, $char);
        if ($pos === false) {
            unset($array[$key]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "cab"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bad"
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/fU99Gdtd

Comment: Great. Any idea how to re-index the array after you unset some of its elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$source = "abcdef";
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $ichr = strlen($value) - 1;
  // traverses each character in string
  for($i=0; $i<$ichr; $i++) {
    if(stristr($value{$i}) === false) {
      unset($array[$key]);
      break;
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("abc","defg","asd","ade","de","fe");
$source = "abcde";
foreach ($array as $key => $string){
  for($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++){
    if(strpos($source, $string[$i])===false){
       unset($array[$key]);
   }
  } 
}
```

Now the array looks like

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "ade"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "de"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to filter ( remove ) the characters, that are not defined in the $source variable. By Mark Baker comments, this is what you need:

```
$source = str_split ( "abdef" );    //defined characters
$target = str_split ( "atyutyu" );  //string to be filtered

$result = array_intersect ( $target, $source );
echo implode( $result );    // output will be only "a"
```

And full example:

```
$source = str_split ( "abdef" );
$txts = array ( "alfa", "bravo", "charlie", "delta" );

function filter ( $toBeChecked, $against )
{
    $target = str_split ( $toBeChecked );
    return implode ( array_intersect ( $target, $against ) );
}
foreach ( $txts as &$value )
{
    $value = filter ( $value, $source );
}
foreach ( $txts as $value )
{
    echo $value . ", ";
}
//output afa, ba, ae, ae
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
    'abacab',
    'baccarat',
    'bejazzle',
    'barcode',
    'zyx',
);


$source = "abcde";
$sourceArray = str_split($source);

foreach($array as $value) {
    $matches = array_intersect($sourceArray, str_split($value));
    echo $value;
    if (count($matches) == 0) {
        echo ' contains none of the characters ', $source, PHP_EOL;
    } elseif (count($matches) == count($sourceArray)) {
        echo ' contains all of the characters ', $source, PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo ' contains ', count($matches), ' of the characters ', $source, ' (', implode($matches), ')', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

gives

```
abacab contains 3 of the characters abcde (abc)
baccarat contains 3 of the characters abcde (abc)
bejazzle contains 3 of the characters abcde (abe)
barcode contains all of the characters abcde
zyx contains none of the characters abcde
```